# catkin can't find python service files

Tags: ros, catkin, rospy, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a python node which runs a service server.   Catkin builds it fine and builds the service files (works fine for another package in C++ which uses the same .srv file).    Even though it builds the file fine, at runtime the node can't import it.   If I revise the python search path as shown:

```
PYTHONPATH='/home/blake/Projects/Ros/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/retractor_ros/srv/':$PYTHONPATH
```

it works.     Here's my CMakelist.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(retractor_ros)

set(BH_LIB_NAME XXXXXXXXXXX)


## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRE COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  ${BH_LIB_NAME}
)
 
 
## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
   FILES
   PhidgetsServoCommand.srv
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
)
 
## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )
 
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS 
#   LIBRARIES ${BH_LIB_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime rospy roscpp std_msgs rstate_machine
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
########### 
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
#   /opt/ros/hydro/include/turtle_actionlib
  /home/blake/Projects/Ros/catkin_ws/devel/include/retractor_ros
  /home/blake/Projects/Ros/catkin_ws/src/pwm_ros
  /home/blake/Projects/Ros/catkin_ws/src/rstate_machine/include
)
  

## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(retractor_ros_node retractor_fsm.cpp keyinput.cpp)
target_link_libraries(retractor_ros_node ${BH_LIB_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node servo_fsm_generate_messages_cpp keyinput.cpp rstate_machine.cpp)
  
install(PROGRAMS
   scripts/pwm_servo.py
   ../devel/lib/retractor_ros/retractor_ros_node
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
   )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
install(TARGETS retractor_ros_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167906/catkin-can%27t-find-python-service-files/) by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect this happens because you aren't importing the service module correctly in your python node.

I suspect you're doing:

```
import PhidgetsServoCommand
```

Instead, you should be doing:

```
from retractor_ros.srv import PhidgetsServoCommand
```

We can debug more if you add the import line from your node and the python error you're receiving to your question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-05-22**:
Thanks - your fix worked!   To bad it's not in the documentation !

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-05-22**:
Actually it is part of the first rospy Service tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient

**Comment by [blakeh](https://answers.ros.org/users/14931/blakeh/) on 2014-05-22**:
Now that I can import, i find that I can't actually start the service.   Basically my project was working as long as I used the "AddTwoInts" service but I think somehow .h files from the ros distribution were sneaking into my build.  Now that I have changed the name to "PhidgetsServoCommand", I had trouble above.  Now that that is fixed, I can't do rospy.Service().   I'm going to post a new question with details...  (Thanks again!)